# Which Linode stackScript is best for PHP and Ruby on Rails production environment?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, vps

I'm completely new to setting up a server.

Which [Linode StackScript](http://www.linode.com/stackscripts/browse/) is most suited (would require less configuration) for deploying web apps written in PHP as well as in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to get a RoR instance, since it's more difficult to configure. PHP is quite easy to install/configure.

See this setup: http://www.linode.com/stackscripts/view/?StackScriptID=207

Yvan